# PostgresQL Syntax Error at end of input, how do I troubleshoot this?

Tags: syntax-error

I am getting an error in my PostGresQL code.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
Position: 250
FROM
tutorial.crunchbase_companies

This usually works so I am not sure what my error means.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What does "percent total of distinct count" mean?

Comment: As far as I can see, the error message is raised because you are missing a closing paranthesis at the end.

Comment: Your last column when you try to divide by after the 100 you have an open paren (  but no closing one anywhere.

Comment: Check your syntax, commas, closing brackets etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want the total companies, the companies with non-NULL values for a column and the ratio.

If so, this has nothing to do with `distinct`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       COUNT(funding_total_usd) as num_with_funding,
       AVG( (funding_total_usd IS NOT NULL)::int ) as ratio_with_funding
FROM tutorial.crunchbase_companies;
```